# ElasticSearch not able to search special characters from a word

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have indexed my pdf file in elastic search using ingest-attachment processor plugin and now am search my file based on the contents available in PDF.

For Example, am having some contents like this in my pdf.

`Hello I m  Karthikeyan. My mail id Karthikeyan@gmail.com, My mob no 4573894833.`

While am searching using Java API, am able to search like the following.

Search For,

`Karthikeyan@gmail.com`  am able to get the file.
But,
If i search for,
`@gm`  means am not able to get the file, am expecting that i should get the file because, this file have my search keyword `@gm`.

How can i do this. ?

Am using tokenizer with `min_gram` & `max_gram` as 3 each.

Please find the below java api that i have used, but none of them giving me the results as expected.

```
QueryStringQueryBuilder attachmentQB = new QueryStringQueryBuilder("@gm");
```

Please find my below mappings details.

```
PUT attach_local
    {

  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 3,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "attachment": {
          "properties": {
            "content": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
            },
            "content_length": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "content_type": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "language": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "resume": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see how ES tokenizes your search text using

```
POST /attach_local/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
   "text": "@gm"
}
```

That will tell you if the @ character is dropped or not. If it is then that would explain the behavior since your inverted index has all trigrams and you are searching for a bigram.